# how to continously scan for the amount of numbers inside of an array

Tags: arrays, c

I currently am having a small trouble in my code, I am supposed to make a program that adds / sums all numbers inside of an array, while I have no problem in doing that, I currently have a problem with the part in which you are supposed to scan the numbers to be put in the array, here are the example of the input

```
3
5
1 2 3 4 5
8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

What this means is that, the user inputs number "3" as it means to create 3 arrays, the number "5" afterward means to put 5 numbers inside of the array (1 2 3 4 5), after the user has inputted the numbers inside of an array, the user inputs "8" which means to make another array consisting of 8 numbers, and then putting numbers into the array again, and so on.

However I am having a problem in which after inputting all the numbers in the array that consists of 5 number, the program instead inputs 5 number into another array again (instead of asking the amount of numbers to be put inside of another array), so instead the number "8 1 2 3 4" gets inputted in another array, and I did not know which part I did wrong.

Here are my C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x, y;
    int i;
    int n;
    int c=1;
    int count=0;
    int sum=0;

    scanf("%d", &y); //this determines the amount of array to be inputted
    scanf("%d", &x); //this determines the amount of numbers to be inputted inside of an array
    int line[x];

    for(int i=0; i<y; i++){
        sum=0;
        for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
            scanf("%d", &line[i]); //scan number for the array
            sum += line[i];
        }   
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n", c, sum);//output of all sum
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You only `scanf` into `x` once, so this should be wholly unsurprising. You need to put that in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the size for each array - currently you only read it once.
e.g.:

```cpp
int numLines;
scanf("%d", &numLines);

for(int lineIdx = 0; lineIdx < numLines; lineIdx++) {
    // read the number of elements for each array
    int numNumbers;
    scanf("%d", &numNumbers);

    int line[numNumbers];

    for(int i = 0; i < numNumbers; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &line[i]);
    }
}
```

Additionally you can avoid storing the individual numbers, since you're only interested in the sum, e.g.:

```cpp
int sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < numNumbers; i++) {
    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    sum += number;
}
```

Also you could defer outputting the sums until all inputs have been processed, so it doesn't visually get interleaved into the input.

This would be a possible way to write that program: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xfd6dfc6n)

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // get the number of arrays we need to read
    int numLines;
    scanf("%d", &numLines);

    // The sums of each array
    int sums[numLines];

    for(int lineIdx = 0; lineIdx < numLines; lineIdx++) {
      // read the number of elements for each array
      int numNumbers;
      scanf("%d", &numNumbers);

      // sum up all the numbers of the array
      sums[lineIdx] = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < numNumbers; i++) {
        int number;
        scanf("%d", &number);
        sums[lineIdx] += number;
      }
    }

    // after all arrays have been entered,
    // output the sums for each case:
    for(int lineIdx = 0; lineIdx < numLines; lineIdx++) {
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n", lineIdx, sums[lineIdx]);
    }
}
```